# Rails dynamic div id in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, chartkick

I'am creating a rails UI that shows a list of graph, the number of graph shown is based on the number of unique entries from the table. At the moment I got the graph to hide via Jquery using the below code:

```
<div class = "Row">
  <% Visit.pluck("country").uniq.each do |input| %>
    <div class = "GraphDiv" id = "Graph_<%= input.to_s%>">
      <%= link_to "#{input}", "#", class: "graph-show" %>
      <div class = "GraphDis">
       ... Chartkick stuff ... 
 </div>
```

and the follow Jquery code on a seperate JS file

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(".graph-show").click(function(){
        $(this).nextAll().slideToggle("slow", "linear");
    });
});
```

What I want to implement is a menu on the side bar with tick boxes for each graph that allows the user to hide and un-hide the graph. However I can't seems to reference the unique ID of each graph from outside

Comment: What do you mean from "outside?

Comment: why is this rails related?

Comment: @huanson It's possible he's having trouble understanding how to pass param data around in rails, which makes for a valid rails question. But I'm not sure if that's the issue and would like to more clarification.

Comment: he is having some other problems. using link_to "#{input}" is showing that. no offense :-)

Comment: if i understand correct, .GraphDis should be display: none and the .graph-show:onlick should set the display: block.

don't know why he needs some unique IDs or rails

Comment: @huanson Seems he has a list of graphs he wants to toggle individually. What you're suggesting would toggle them all.

Comment: Sorry if the original question isn't very clear. I'm trying to create a dashboard of sort that I want to toggle the graph individually from another control that need to reference the dynamically generated ID. And yes I don't quite understand how variables, id and such flows around between rails view and java scripts since I've only started a week ago.